# Would carnivorous people be obvious?

Tags: humans

If humanity were fully adapted to eating and digesting nothing but meat, would the differencewith normal humans be visible from the outside?

Comment: That depends on what you mean specifically by "eating and digesting nothing but meat". Anatomically modern humans are adapted to eat and digest cooked food, with some small uncooked supplements consisting of particularly tender fruit, leaves and such. If you mean "adapted to eat uncooked food" (of any kind, vegetable, flesh, fish, doesn't matter) the anatomical differences would be pretty obvious.

Comment: @AlexP, citation needed. I fail to see why a human with the GI system of, say, a pig, would be "pretty obvious". *Maybe* dentition, although now we need clarification of "visible from the outside".

Comment: @Matthew: Our jaws are too small to eat uncooked food -- we simply don't have enough space for muscle attachment points, and the jaw bones are too gracile. Our teeth are also too small, and of the wrong shape. Look at our very close cousins the chipanzees to see how a human-like animal looks when adapted to eat raw food.

Comment: Alex, matt... WHY are you two bickering about cooked vs. uncooked? The OP asks about carnivorous (as vs. omnivorous)

Comment: we already have human populations that eat nothing but meat, native Mongolian and Inuit come to mind.

Comment: look for sign of scurvy...

Comment: @user6760 Carnivorous-adapted humans should not have this problem as long as they eat organ meats (why wouldn't they?) and do not cook (like the Inuit). It is like saying a snake should have scurvy because it eats no vegetables. But humans, especially in the Western World, tend to only eat muscle and we cook it. They could also possibly regain their ability to produce their own Vitamin C.

Answer (score 8):

### Likely Not (on some broad assumptions):

Given that humans can adapt their environments around them to their needs, it is quite possible that humans (if they TODAY became obligate carnivores) wouldn't look significantly different. After all, they got there with the equipment they have - tiny mouths and no fangs or claws. Humans don't NEED those things to kill everything in their environment.

I'm not sure what conditions you want to impose to make people carnivores. As John pointed out, there are populations that do this already, and few carnivores are utterly and exclusively carnivore. It's more a line drawn by people, and has a lot more subtlety.

But a human with a gun/bow, a knife, and fire is more than capable of switching to a carnivorous diet. They don't need to look like predators to do so. Most of the meat humans eat today isn't hunted anyway.  If you were trying to adapt a herbivore to carnivore behavior, it might be different. But humans already have adaptations to be predators, most critically in our body plan (efficient endurance predator) and our eyes (forward facing/excellent stereoscopic sight).

It's also entirely possible that going forward, carnivore humans might have evolutionary pressures that would shift them in a different direction for digestion (not usually obvious from outside) dentition (whatever is most efficient for chewing cooked meat) or pupil shape (if we become nocturnal or ambush predators). If we stopped being endurance predators, our body shape might shift as well. We might see people undergoing speciation as different hunting niches are filled by humans. Not being gatherers might have (in the long run) unforeseen consequences on what we looked like.

But given a start of modern humans with a small shift to make us obligate carnivores, I think humans would be perfectly adapted. Most of our meat would NOT come from hunting, but animal husbandry. We would continue to gather food for cows, goats, chickens and sheep. There would be a larger emphasis on what parts of animals we ate (to give the best nutrition) but otherwise more meat would just displace the "and potatoes" part of the dinner table. DKNguyen wisely pointed out there are some vitamins damaged by cooking, and our carnivores would likely need to use various compensations to deal with that (fermentation, chemical marinating like with lemon juice/lye [think lutefisk] and supplements) but even cats may potentially eat [grass](https://www.petmd.com/cat/wellness/evr_ct_eating_grass) as a source of folic acid, so your carni-humans might season food with plants containing trace nutrients.

Comment: As well as reduced cooking since cooking destroys a lot of the components that are in meat (especially organ meats) that we would otherwise have to eat FRESH fruits and vegetables for.

Comment: @DKNguyen true, although the internal organs tend to be less tough and are probably easier to eat raw than muscle. Never tried raw liver; never personally cared for sweetmeats either. Maybe marinating/pickling?

Comment: You know, pickiling never occurred to me but sailors had scurvy from preserved foods so I assume it may have the same effect. Whatever the case, time likely has the same degrading effect no matter what you do. A big reason why we must cook is that we do not eat our food fresh from the kill; We essentially eat a bacteria-ridden corpse killed elsewhere some time ago. That raises a potential farming issue for large populations in an urban environment.

Comment: @DKNguyen The German Navy got vitamin C from fermenting cabbage (sauerkraut) so bacterial activity could be an important nutritional supplement. Some people will hang meat (basically letting it rot for a while) to make it "tender." Sound gross to me, but hey.

Comment: I'm going to have to read up on what preservation methods do and do not destroy Vitamin C. Did European sailors just not know to preserve fruits and vegetables? Seems unlikely. Or just super adverse to preserved organ meats?

Comment: Surprisingly difficult to find. Some articles say pickling destroys Vitamin C while others say Sauerkraut is high in Vitamin C, but nothing that talks about both at the same time. I finally found one that did say after fermenting the cabbage, the Vitamin C can be 20 times higher than before so that does point to microbial activity but still does not explain why pickling other things destroys Vitamin C but not in this case.

Comment: @DKNguyen Some of it is that people treat pickling, canning, and fermenting as being synonymous. A lot of it has to do with canning (which is cooking, after all), which does degrade many vitamins. Pickling often goes hand-in-hand with canning, but I like fresh pickled veggies better than canned, personally. Most sauerkraut is cooked when eaten, so I'm not sure if it's the cooking causing the loss or something else. This site suggests a lot is lost to solubilization in H2O. https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/cooking-nutrient-content#boiling-simmering-and-poaching

Comment: Is Sauerkraut heated during pickling? I don't know why sailors did not bring pickled foods since the technology must have already existed at the time. They did not have cans back then, or glass jars.

Comment: The actual fermentation (there is some salt, but I don't think of it as pickling) doesn't. My family didn't cook it first, at least. This is a nice, simple recipe, and I highly recommend caraway. PS use the juices from the sauerkraut to flavor other foods and you save a lot of the nutrients. Then again, a lot of German food is a little sour. https://farmandwilderness.org/2020/05/06/how-to-make-sauerkraut/?gclid=CjwKCAiA9bmABhBbEiwASb35VylEr_8F_oAv_XKvF2F-l0QiGHA74zrrkfnsH7agM1-5I7v6KSeyExoC-5MQAvD_BwE

Comment: Apparently that "20 times higher Vitamin C after pickling than before" is just wrong. It completely misunderstands what its source is saying.

Answer (score 4):

Tigers, leopard seals and wolves are carnivore.

Let's compare their "smiling devices" with those of a human.

For a tiger this is what they look like

[image: Tiger fangs]

These are those of a leopard seal

[image: leopard seal fangs]

These are those of a wolf

[image: wolf fangs]

And these are those of a human

[image: human teeth]

I guess the differences are pretty obvious:

- bigger canines and incisive
- teeth intended to cut and lacerate, not to smash
- jaw intended to have a broader opening to better bite the prey

Comment: Let's also add in that the mouth would likely also have less side-to-side mobility than it does for us and smaller cheeks, as a carnivorous diet usually requires a less flexible jaw more focused on opening and closing movement  and on a wider gape

Comment: These jaw changes would be required to change Humans into Predators, not to change them into Carnivores. Those jaws are designed to eat raw meat from prey... And to hunt and kill the prey in the first place. OP does not specify hunter. OP does not even specify uncooked.

Comment: Do notice though that our closest relatives, chimps, have some really big mouths and canine teeth and they are omnivores just like us. Our teeth evolved to be "cuter" because we didn't need to masticate so much after mastering fire and tools.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a (mainly) carnivore sub-species, named [Neanderthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal). While I still learned in school that their physical appearance was because of their meat-only diet, nowadays it is known that neither they only fed on meat, nor was their appearance completely influenced by it. Depending on the scenario, you still can pick some interesting parts. We believed the original "historical facts" for that long probably only because it sounded cool.

You can find some pictures on Google to look at. Below is an example. They had a bit stronger appearance and were larger (for their time).

[image: Neanderthal - reconstruction by Adam Sacco, original source gone]